# async, await and strange result

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing application on WP 8.1. One of my method is parsing html and everything was ok. But I want to change coding to have polish characters.
So I must to have Length properties to variable type byte[]. To make this possible I need to use **await** and changed my method on **asnych**.

```
public async void GetTimeTable(string href, int day)
{
    string htmlPage = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);

        char[] decoded = new char[response.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            if (response[i] < 128)
                decoded[i] = (char)response[i];
            else if (response[i] < 0xA0)
                decoded[i] = '\0';
            else
                decoded[i] = (char)iso8859_2[response[i] - 0xA0];
        }
        htmlPage = new string(decoded);
    }

    // further code... and on the end::
    TimeTableCollection.Add(xxx);
} 

public ObservableCollection<Groups> TimeTableCollection { get; set; }
```

Method is calling from MainPage.xaml.cs

```
vm.GetTimeTable(navContext.HrefValue, pivot.SelectedIndex);
TimeTableViewOnPage.DataContext = vm.TimeTableCollection;
```

And now is my question. Why vm.TimeTableCollection is null? When I don't use async and await everything is ok and vm.TimeTableCollection has x elements.

Comment: You are not awaiting `GetTimeTable` so control continues to the next line before it has completed. There are lots of examples on SO about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now is my question. Why vm.TimeTableCollection is null?

Because you're executing an `async` operation without `await`ing it. Hence, the request may not be complete when you access your `vm` property in the next line.

You need to change your method signature to `async Task` and `await` it:

```
public async Task GetTimeTableAsync(string href, int day)
{
    string htmlPage = string.Empty;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(URL);

        char[] decoded = new char[response.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            if (response[i] < 128)
                decoded[i] = (char)response[i];
            else if (response[i] < 0xA0)
                decoded[i] = '\0';
            else
                decoded[i] = (char)iso8859_2[response[i] - 0xA0];
        }
        htmlPage = new string(decoded);
    }

    // further code... and on the end::
    TimeTableCollection.Add(xxx);
}
```

and then:

```
await vm.GetTimeTableAsync(navContext.HrefValue, pivot.SelectedIndex);
```

This means your top calling method has to become async as well. This is usually the behavior when dealing with async methods, you need to go [*async all the way*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Note, to follow TPL guidelines, you should mark any `async` method with the `Async` postfix, Hence `GetTimeTable` should be `GetTimeTableAsync`

Answer (score 0):

You're not awaiting the result:

```
await vm.GetTimeTable(navContext.HrefValue, pivot.SelectedIndex);
TimeTableViewOnPage.DataContext = vm.TimeTableCollection;
```

If you don't `await` an async method, the program will execute it, and continue to execute the following code without waiting for it to finish.