# Wait to complete async method

Tags: c#, sqlite, async-await

I have async method which insert data into database:

```
public async void InsertRoutes(ObservableCollection<RouteEO> routes)
{
  connection.CreateTableAsync<RouteEO>().ContinueWith((result) =>
  {
     Debug.WriteLine("Routes table created");
     foreach (var route in routes)
     {
        var query = connection.Table<RouteEO>().
                      Where(v => v.InspectionId == route.InspectionId && v.EO_id == route.EO_id);

        query.ToListAsync().ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Route record inserted or updated");
           if (t.Result.Any())
                 connection.UpdateAsync(route);
           else
                 connection.InsertAsync(route);
         });
     }
    });
}
```

I want to call it and execute next line of the code only when the method execution will be completed:

```
sqlController.InsertInspections(DataController.InspectionList);
Debug.WriteLine("Done");
```

But when I launch this code I get "Done" message in the Debug window before "Table created" and "Record inserted" messages.

Why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: `async void` is supported *only* to support asynchronous UI event handlers.  (Consider it a "backward compatibility case.)  Outside of that specific use case, ***never*** use `async void`.  (Not only because it prevents tasks from being awaited properly but it also prevents the system from knowing if anything went wrong during the execution of the task.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [async, await and strange result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062412/async-await-and-strange-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer to my question:  https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/tests/AsyncTests.cs

```
    [Test]
    public void TestAsyncTableQueryToListAsync ()
    {
        var conn = GetConnection ();
        conn.CreateTableAsync<Customer> ().Wait ();

        // create...
        Customer customer = this.CreateCustomer ();
        conn.InsertAsync (customer).Wait ();

        // query...
        var query = conn.Table<Customer> ();
        var task = query.ToListAsync ();
        task.Wait ();
        var items = task.Result;

        // check...
        var loaded = items.Where (v => v.Id == customer.Id).First ();
        Assert.AreEqual (customer.Email, loaded.Email);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn `async Task` instead of `async void` and `await` your method:

```
public async Task InsertRoutes(ObservableCollection<RouteEO> routes)
```

And then:

```
await sqlController.InsertInspections(DataController.InspectionList);
Debug.WriteLine("Done");
```